# Given a graph, how to build another "difficult" isomorphic graph from it?

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Suppose I want to test an algorithm for graph isomorphism check.

Starting from a given graph, I would do a random permutation of vertices to build the second graph.

Is there a way of making another isomorphic graph that is "more difficult" to check?

Comment: No, because given any labelling of a graph you can make a random labelling of that. So every labelling is equally difficult.  That doesn't mean a particular algorithm will take the same time for each labelling.

Comment: Maybe it's more interesting to ask for a non-isomorphic graph that is difficult to check?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson yes, right.